# Convert iterable to list using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, iterable

I have a simple loop that adds elements from one `list` to another `list`.
How can the same result be achieved using `streams`?

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
for(User user: userRepository.findAll()) {
    users.add(user);
}
```

The reason for doing so is because
`userRepository.findAll()` **returns** `Iterable<User>`

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Why use streams?

Comment: @Olivier The only reason for using `streams` is to be better with them.

Comment: But it is not "better" with them.  Streams are not automatically "better".  And in this case, they are not.  As you can see, a Stream-based solution is more complicated, and it won't be  more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

`spliterator()` converts `Iterable` in `stream` and then collect it as a `List` using `collect()`

```java
List<User> users = 
  StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```